# If convergent , what would be the value of the integral?

Tags: integration

Is the integral $ \int_{-2}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx $ convergent  ?

If convergent , what would be the value of the integral ?

**Answer:**

$ \int_{-2}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx =\int_{-2}^{0} \frac{1}{x} dx+\int_{0}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx=\int_{0}^{2} \frac{1}{x} dx+\int_{0}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx=[\ln (x)]_{0}^{2}+ [\ln(x) ]_{0}^{3}$, which diverges as $\ln (0)$ is undefined.

**Am I right?**

Answer (score 2):

no.

If you take the limit of $0$ and do the integral you won't get a real value but an indeterminate form.

when you take the limit you get $-\infty+\infty$(the reason it is different from what you got is because the need to take the limit, and then you can see that it is indeterminate form)

We can calculate this with "Cauchy principal value" and get:

$$\int_{-2}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx =\lim_{a\to0^+}\left(\int_{-2}^{-a} \frac{1}{x} dx+\int_{a}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx\right)=\ln\left(\frac32\right)$$

---

Another way to see it is the following:

---

$\frac1x$ is an odd function, hence $\int_{-a}^a\frac1x dx=0$

So $$\int_{-2}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx=\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{1}{x} dx+\int_{2}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx=0+\int_{2}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx=\int_{2}^{3} \frac{1}{x} dx=\ln\left(\frac32\right)$$

Comment: Note that when I take the limit in the first way it is right side limit. Without this note it doesn't make sense